# Force user to write excerpt before saving post?

Tags: categories, excerpt, save-post

Is it possible, in functions.php, to force users by default to write an excerpt before they can save a post?  And ideally, would it be possible to make this mandatory in only certain post categories?

Comment: did you look at this post: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/124422/mandatory-excerpt-for-custom-post-type

Comment: Wow, no, missed it.  That looks exactly what I wanted.  Thanks.